# Can't get POST value when submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

So here's my HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action="/process_forgot">
       <input type="text" name="name" value="test">
       <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And `/process_forgot`

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo "good";
}
else{
    echo "string";
}
```

And all I get back is `string`. Which is weird because I'm posting the value and I set the `name`. I've done this tons of times, this is the only time i've ever had an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You should inspect the network tab of the dev tools and have a look if there is a 301 or any kind of redirect. This is a common reason for lost post params.

Comment: Or even an internal redirect

Comment: Could you show us any more of your code?

Comment: See if this PHP file works for you: https://gist.github.com/SeerUK/a87527c68b434a18eb08 It works for me.

Comment: is this form in another form? Nested forms cause some problems.

Comment: Your code works fine..

Comment: I agree with Indra. If you want to troubleshoot, replace `echo "string"` with `var_dump $_POST` to check the $_POST contents.

Comment: The code worked fine and as expected returned "good" when I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the .php extension to the file location `process_forgot`...this should fix the issue because without that you have a redirect and all the POST data are lost; for this reason it always runs `echo "string"`.

Answer (score -2):

1) It may sound dumb, but try to see if you require a .php extension in the end of process_forgot in your action.
2) Try directly going to [YourWebsite]/[YourDirectory]/process_forgot.php and see if the file is accessible. You will, depending on your code, probably get a blank page, but that is expected.
3) Check if there is any other problem in your code that is preventing the script from running **properly**.

Comment: *"all I get back is `string`"* is a pretty good indication that his script is running.

Comment: Cool. So my answer was the same as the accepted one, but I get downvotes.